# How to implement separate action from async API call?

Tags: c#, api

I'm trying to implement an API service: when the site controller receives the API call, I would like it to check the request data and return response with success or failure depending on the requested data format.

At the same time, if the request format is correct, there needs to be an action A at the server to execute and then send a separate response message to the caller with a callback URL, which is specified in the original request from the caller. How to implement the spawning of the execution thread for the separate action A?

Pseudo code:

```cs
[HttpPost("Api/Action")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction([FromBody] ActionData actionData)
{
    if (actionData == null)
        return new BadRequestObjectResult("Invalid data");
   
     // spawn a thread to handle the action data
    
     return new OkObjectResult("success");
}

public async Task SeparateAction(ActionData actiondata)
{
    // handle the data here
    using (httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        // prepare the HTTP response here 
        return await httpClient.PostAsync(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure the action is executed one the initial successful response has been sent, then the only reliable solution is a [basic distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html), as described on my blog. Specifically, you need a durable queue and a separate background processor.

Before returning the initial response, your API places a message in the queue. Since this is a durable queue, the message is flushed to disk before the initial response is returned. Then, the background processor takes messages from that queue, processes them (including sending the final processed notification), and deletes them.

Just spinning off a separate thread or using an in-memory queue can cause loss of work any time the process is shut down (e.g., during a rolling upgrade).